# File Upload Múltiplo via aJax - PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, upload, multiple-file-upload

Estou tentando fazer upload de arquivos via ajax e PHP com os seguintes códigos abaixo e não  está dando certo. Não estou conseguindo identificar o que estou fazendo de errado.

**Página**

```
<div id="bsUpload">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" class="fileUpload"><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" class="fileUpload"><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" class="fileUpload"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="btEnviar" value="Fazer Upload"> 
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq(function(){
    
    var bsUpload = $jq("#bsUpload");
    
    bsUpload.on('click', 'input[name="btEnviar"]', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    
        formdata = new FormData(this);
        
        $jq.ajax({
            type: 'POST', cache: false, processData: false, contentType: false, 
            url: 'upload.php', data: formdata,
            success: function(j){
                            alert(j);
                         }
            });
    });
    
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

foreach($_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] as $key => $error){
    if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        $name = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'][$key], '../../upload/'.$name);
    }
}

echo 'Envio OK';

?>
```

**O Erro:**

> Notice: Undefined index: fileUpload in C:\xampp\htdocs\exemplos\upload-ajax\ModeloC\js\Ajax\upload.php on line 3
>
> Warnig: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\exemplos\upload-ajax\ModeloC\js\Ajax\upload.php on line 3

**Deu certo**

Muito obrigado, pela ajuda pessoal

Comment: O que exatamente não está funcionando? Dá algum erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você cria o `FormData` para enviar mas como não adiciona nenhum dos arquivos nele e seu POST acaba indo vazio.

Veja como você pode fazer:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq(function(){

    var bsUpload = $jq("#bsUpload");

    bsUpload.on('click', 'input[name="btEnviar"]', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var formdata = new FormData();

        $jq.when($jq('.fileUpload').each(function(i,e) {
            // adiciona uma entrada em "formdata" para cada campos de classe "fileUpload" com arquivo selecionado
            var file = e.files[0];
            if(file)
                formdata.append('fileUpload['+i+']', file);
        })).done(function(){
            $jq.ajax({
                type: 'POST', cache: false, processData: false, contentType: false, 
                url: 'upload.php', data: formdata,
                success: function(j){
                   alert(j);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

E como @Daniela citou, para evitar este tipo de erro no PHP você deve sempre verificar se o índice realmente existe no array.

Seu PHP ficaria assim:

```
if (isset($_FILES['fileUpload'])) {
    foreach($_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] as $key => $error){
        if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
            $name = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'][$key];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'][$key], '../../upload/'.$name);
        }
    }

    echo 'Envio ok';

} else {
    echo 'Nenhum arquivo enviado';
}
```

Você deve adicionar mais algumas verificações no seu código PHP para ter certeza de que os arquivos foram realmente enviados e nenhum erro ocorreu no processo.

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro alerta é por que você não verificou se `fileUpload` era um *index* de `$_FILES`.

```
<?php    
if (isset($_FILES['fileUpload'])) {

}
```

O segundo erro ocorreu por que você está tentando iterar `$_FILES['fileUpload']['error']` que não é um array, neste caso deve usar *switch*.

```
<?php    
if (isset($_FILES['fileUpload'])) {
    switch ($_FILES['fileUpload']["error"]) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:        
            break;
    }
}
```