# Upload de arquivos com o AJAX

Tags: ajax, upload

Estou participando de um projeto porém não consigo fazer o upload de arquivos utilizando ajax.

MODEL

```
    <?php // You need to add server side validation and better error handling here

$data = array();

if(isset($_GET['files']))
{ 
  $error = false;
  $files = array();

  $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/SISPESQ/Sispesq/public/uploads/arquivos/';
  foreach($_FILES as $file)
  {
    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .basename($file['name'])))
    {
      $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $error = true;
    }
  }
  $data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your files') : array('files' => $files);
}
else
{
  $data = array('success' => 'Form was submitted', 'formData' => $_POST);
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Quanto ao AJAX

```
$(function () {

var form;
$('#arquivo').change(function (event) {
    form = new FormData();
    form.append('arquivo', event.target.files[0]); // para apenas 1 arquivo
    //var name = event.target.files[0].content.name; // para capturar o nome do arquivo com sua extenção
});

$('#btnEnviar').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SISPESQ/Sispesq/app/actions/inserirEdital.php?arquivo', // Url do lado server que vai receber o arquivo
        data: form,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            if(data){
                $("#alert").html(data).css({"display": "block"}).addClass('alert alert-success');
            } else {
                $("#alert").html(data).css({"display": "block"}).addClass('alert alert-danger');
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            $("#alert").html(data).css({"display": "block"}).addClass('alert alert-danger');
        }
    });
});
 });
```

VIEW

```
<label>Nome:</label>
              <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite aqui o nome do edital" required/>
            </div>
            <input type="file" id="arquivo" name="arquivo" accept="application/pdf" required/>
            <p class="help-block">Selecione o arquivo .pdf</p>
<button type="submit" id="btnEnviar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Salvar</button>
```

No caso esta aparecendo `error:` nao sei o pq que esta fazendo isso...

Comment: Seja bem-vindo, tem várias erros no seu código, mas que a principio não afetam o resultado final, qual mensagem aparece na resposta do `success:` ou do `error:`?

Comment: [Relacionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27845/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-fazer-upload-de-arquivos-com-ajax), [relacionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax) e [relacionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47780/file-upload-m%C3%BAltiplo-via-ajax-php) Duplicata?

Comment: o codigo ta errado....

Comment: esse e o correto... mas nao da certo..

Comment: Ali na resposta eu coloquei o codigo certo do model

Comment: esta aparecendo error:

Comment: @HappyBR edite a sua pergunta e poste o código certo. Dê mais informações sobre a sua pergunta. Onde você está tendo dificuldade?

Comment: No caso eu nao sei o pq este codigo nao esta funcionando... poderia avaliar e ver o que pode estar fazendo ele falhar?